# I want give a position for item selected of the ListView created in Dialog

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog

I run ListView in Dialog:
main_dialog contains ListView, list_row_dialog contains TextView for style items, dataD2 tableau of objet(university) contains titles of universities.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main_dialog); 

    MediaDialogAdapter adapter = new MediaDialogAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row_dialog, dataD2);       
    listViewDialog = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listDialog);

    listViewDialog.setAdapter(adapter);

    int i = listViewDialog.getCheckedItemPosition();

    dialog.setTitle(titre_album);

    dialog.show();
```

I want give a position for item selected "title university".

Comment: Your question is very vague. Have you ever tried to do something that did not work? What part of your code does't do what you think?

Comment: implement the onitemclick listener and get the value using the position. You could google a little to figure out how on item clicks work with listviews